# Wrapping Text Round Image Issues

Tags: html, css, image

I need your help with image display inside comment box. When ever characters of the comments exceeds a certain number instead of it to wrap round the image to the left, it actually gives the appearance in the picture below. How can I fix this?

```
#comment img.floatright {
    float:right; 
    padding: 1px;
    clear:left;
}
```

**IMAGE**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option would be add the following style to the content that you want to wrap:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
overflow: hidden;
```

The word-wrap setting will allow the word to be wrapped despite its length. The overflow setting will cause it to be cut off at the end of the available space in browsers which don't recognize word-wrap.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Redsz/pBSDd/1/

Answer (score 1):

I would personally set the text inside a `<div>` and define a width, but if you don't want to do that you could create a PHP function to insert `<wbr>` tags whenever there is a long word. The tag will only break up the word when needed so you can implement multiple tags in a word.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/6rBUZ/